# custom urls and views in oscar

Tags: python, django, django-oscar

I can't seem to get the urls to match in oscar. My oscar app is a subapp in my main app. My understanding is to create views and urls in the `app.py` in the sub modules in oscar.It keeps throwing `NoReverseMatch`. Oscar pages all loads, just not my custom views

in myapp/shop/dashboard/app.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from oscar.core.application import DashboardApplication
from oscar.core.loading import get_class
from views import HomeViews
class DashboardApplication(DashboardApplication):

    def get_urls(self):
        urls = [
            url(r'^someurl/', HomeViews.dosomething, name="hi"),
        ]
        return self.post_process_urls(urls)

application = DashboardApplication()
```

in myapp/shop/dashboard/views.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db.models import User
from oscar.app.partner.models import Partner
from django.middleware.csrf import get_token
from oscar.apps.dashboard.views import HomeView as CoreHomeView

class HomeView(CoreHomeView):
    def dosomething(request):
        return HttpResponse("hello")
```

in my main app, I registered the shop in my settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS =[
...
]] + get_core_apps(['shop'])
```

and in my main app url I have included oscar urls

```
from shop.app import application as shop_app
urlpatterns = i18n_patterns(
    url(r'^shop/', include(shop_app.urls)),
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend the existing urls list, not replace it. That is mostly why you get no reverse match errors because the default urls that oscar might have, don't exist anymore. For any other non-oscar-forked app, this would have been okay (just your own urls and nothing else).

```
class DashboardApplication(DashboardApplication):

    def get_urls(self):
        my_urls = [
            url(r'^someurl/', HomeViews.dosomething, name="hi"),
        ]
        default_urls = super(DashboardApplication, self).get_urls()
        return self.post_process_urls(my_urls) + default_urls
```